# GAL_NOT_FOUND Error with Google Home Assistant

Tags: google-home, google-assistant

We have a skill at Google Home Action that control AC devices. Yesterday we came across this issue that Google Assistant unable to full fill the device control command and keep giving unable to reach or skill is unavailable right now. AC devices are being controlled by the Google Home app in screen control but failing to control via Google Assistants.

We have API endpoint deploy on AWS that full fill the commands, query, sync and authorization flow. When google assistant giving error we do not received any logs at API side for such request or failure.
We walk through the logs of Google Home Action at Google cloud and found that it is giving us two errors.

- GAL_NOT_FOUND
- BACKEND_FAILURE_URL_UNREACHABLE

We are unable to identity the issue with the above error.

As mentioned in the documentation of [Google Home Action](https://developers.home.google.com/cloud-to-cloud/analytics/troubleshooting#platform_error_codes) we have performed the Account Re-Linking but even though unable to make it work. For now we have enabled the advanced monitoring for more error detail but for as of now unable to identity the issue.

Answer (score 0):

- You are trying to use an endpoint that Google servers cannot communicate with (are you returning a 5** error ?) and you have to check the endpoints you use for account linking.
- For this you can try out the [Connect smart home devices to the Google Assistant codelab](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/codelabs/smarthome-washer#0)  with your current endpoints to see if the error is due to a configuration, or the server you are running behind your endpoint.
- If you are still running into issues I recommend going through the [Troubleshooting Guide](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/develop/troubleshooting) and/or starting with new project with the codelab and replace it step by step to see where the issue is.